# wp-head() find code that hooks in it?

Tags: wordpress

I have code that is outputted by wp_head that I need to remove from a website. I cannot find where this code hooks into the wp_head action.

I tried searching my whole wordpress site recursively for a small bit of text.

I tried searching for 'wp_head' and I couldn't find it that way.

It almost seems like wp_head has like a GTM tag in it somewhere and that the code i need to remove is included through something like that.

Does anybody know of a way to search and track down unwanted code that is hooked somewhere??

The particular code I need to remove is a  tag that is being outputted by wp_head.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_head()` function is located in `wp-includes/general-template.php`

You should read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head

Note: Most of default actions into the 'wp-head' hook by WordPress core are set up in wp-includes/default-filters.php. If you need to remove a default hook, this file will give you the priority for which to use to remove the hook.

Comment: Thanks - the default-filters.php at least tells me all the actions that hook into wp_head - so now I have more things to search for! This is a big help.